# Undefined index in session variable

Tags: php, session

I am trying to send the product Id of the specific productId via sessions using php [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHafy.png)
Like When I click One of these I want to pass the Specific Product Id to my Next Page [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Angm.png) So that I can Display The Data.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4" ;
$result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
<?php                                                   

$productId =$row['productId'];
$subCatId = $row['subCatId'] ;
$_SESSION['productId'] = $productId;?> //I TRIED THIS WAY BUT SINCE IT IS ON LOOP THIS SETS THE SESSION VARIABLE TO THE PRODUCT THAT IS DISPLAYED AT THE LAST
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE productId = $productId ";
$results= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)): ?>
<?php $raw_url = $rows['pic'];
$urli = "uploads/".$raw_url;
<?php endif ?>
```

I am new to PHP and also have little knowledge on JS. Please Suggest what should I learn to solve this.
Thank you!

Comment: Please don't post images of your code, just post your code. If we need to copy/paste it to replicate the behavior, you're making life extremely difficult for us.

Comment: Your `unset($_SESSION['productId'])` immediately after `$_SESSION['productId'] = $productId` instantly deletes the product id from the session right after you set it. Remove the `unset()` and you should be able to echo it.

Comment: You can do that with 1 query. Look into `join`s. You also need to start the session, and should get in the habit of parameterizing your queries.

Comment: If you  `unset`  `$_SESSION['productId]` your destroy this variable so that's why you obtain such a message.

Comment: @TomaszW. Yeah That Worked Thanks But I am Having an Issue Here
` <?php 
session_start();
include 'includes/db.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['productId'])) `

This Is my next page where I want to use this Id but it says undefined index productId, I have removed the unset() function